# How to inherit @ForeignKey settings when using TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance strategy

Tags: jpa, orm, foreign-keys, hibernate-5.x

I try to control the foreign key name generation using the `@ForeignKey` annotation. This usually works well. But in a special case it does not what I want and I don't know how to configure it.

The special case is when I use `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`. When the base class has a `@ManyToOne` relationship and I want to specify the foreign key name using `@ForeignKey` it only applies for the base class.

```
         +------------+           +--------------+
         | BaseEntity |   ----->  | OtherEntity  |
         +------------+           +--------------+
                ^
                |
       +--------+---------+
  +----------+      +----------+
  |SubEntity1|      |SubEntity2|
  +----------+      +----------+
```

My `BaseEntity`

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table(name = "base_entity")
public class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_other_entity"))
    private OtherEntity otherEntity;
}
```

My `SubEntity1` (same for the the `SubEntity2`)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sub_entity_1")
public class SubEntity1 extends BaseEntity {
}
```

and just to be complete .... the `OtherEntity`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "other_entity")
public class OtherEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}
```

Hibernate will generate a ddl script containing the following foreign key definitions:

```
alter table base_entity 
   add constraint FK_other_entity 
   foreign key (otherEntity_id) 
   references other_entity (id);

alter table sub_entity_1 
   add constraint FK_jtmdc6tiytduxbpesmng9g3bk 
   foreign key (otherEntity_id) 
   references other_entity (id);

alter table sub_entity_2 
   add constraint FK_9xpb6q7qeq5r3pq071cbbiygx 
   foreign key (otherEntity_id) 
   references other_entity (id);
```

As you can see the sub entities foreign key name is random.

The sub entities don't have a field holding a reference to the `OtherEntity`, so I can't place a `@ForeignKey` annotation there.

**How can I control the foreign key name for sub entities when using a table per class inheritence type?**

I'm using

- spring-boot 1.4.3.RELEASE
- hibernate 5.6.2.Final

**EDIT**

I also tried to use [`@AssociationOverride`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AssociationOverride.html), but it does not work.

---

If you need a quick setup for schema generation you might want to take a look at my previous question [Generate DDL with spring boot using a custom delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41894432/974186)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a hibernate bug

- [HHH-10387: In a @AssociationOverride the foreignKey = @ForeignKey is not considered](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10387)
- [HHH-11180
  JPA @ForeignKey still not consistently applied from annotation binding](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11180)

I have **voted** for both bugs. Maybe you want to vote for it too and hopefully it will get fixed soon.

I will observe changes to the issues and update this answer when the bug is fixed.

---

My *"solution for now"* is to use `InheritanceType.JOINED`

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "base_entity")
public class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_other_entity"))
    private OtherEntity otherEntity;
}
```

and set the foreign key of the joined table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sub_entity_1")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_base_entity"))
public class SubEntity1 extends BaseEntity {

}
```