# Hibernate DDL update SQL queries

Tags: sql, hibernate, flyway

I want to save change database scripts in my version control for log and history Or maybe use `Flyway` in feature.

I use hibernate `ddl-auto update` mode in develop time to change and update database schema.

How can get queries that hibernate apply to database when run app in `ddl-auto=update` mode?

Does hibernate give me API or log file or alternative solution?

Any body have suggest?

Comment: check this https://geowarin.github.io/generate-ddl-with-hibernate/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700123/hibernate-5-generate-sql-ddl-into-file

Comment: @aliakbarazizkhani yup. That is clever method and according to 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178041/where-did-configuration-generateschemacreationscript-go-in-hibernate-5'  seems generateSchemaCreationScript function is deprecated and not exists in hibernate 5. I should change and test it with hibernate 5. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

You can set below property for get queries.

```
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql" >true</ prop>
<prop key="hibernate.format_sql" >true</ prop>
<prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
```

Comment: These properties just show generated SQL's in console. This is not answer. I want get generated SQL in separate file or get it through API not in console.